# Sum over finite sets is well-defined

Tags: group-theory, summation, abelian-groups, recursion

Given an abelian additive group $G$ and a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $G$, we're able to define recursively "indexed summation" through :
$$ \sum_{i=0}^0 a_i = a_0 \;\;\;\text{ and }\;\;\; \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}a_i =  \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i + a_{n+1}$$
Then, a set $I$ is said to be finite iff there exists a non-zero positive integer $n$ such that, there exists a bijection $\sigma$ between $I$ and $[1, n] = \{1,...,n\}$. Now, considering a family $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ of elements of $G$ and a finite subset $J\subseteq I$, the most natural way to define summation over finite sets is :
$$ \sum_{i\in J} a_i = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{\sigma(i)} $$
where $\sigma$ denotes a bijection between $J$ and the integer interval $[1,n+1]$.
However, this sum must be well-defined, it means that it holds for any bijection between those sets.

How to prove that this summation is well-defined (without using the symmetric group $S_n$) ?

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: You’re in an abelian group.

Comment: Also, I think all this is overly complicated.

Comment: Defining with $\cdots$ or "words" it's not a rigorous way... :/

Comment: You don’t need to do this for generic $J$:  it will never carry more information than $[1,n]$.

Comment: How about induction over the number of elements/terms?

Comment: @md2perpe yeah... but what is the inductive step ?

Comment: Assume that summation is well-defined for all sets of $n$ elements and show that summation is then well-defined for all sets of $n+1$ elements.

Comment: How ? I don't see how to proceed ?

Comment: Serge Lang, *Algebra* (revised third edition 2002), p.5f. begins with an inductive proof that (in multiplicative notation, for a commutative monoid $G$) $$\prod_{\nu=1}^nx_{\psi(\nu)}=\prod_{\nu=1}^nx_\nu$$ for any permutation $\psi$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Given a set $I$ and a function $f\colon I\to G$ with $f(i)=e$ for almost all $i$, the product $\prod_{i\in I}f(i)$ is defined to mean $\prod_{i\in I_0}f(i)$ "taken in any order (the value does not depend on the order, by the preceding remark)". This seems satisfactory to me, but I'm flummoxed by your requirement that $S_n$ somehow not be used.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the definition $I_0 = \{i \in I : f(i) \ne e\}$.